# Tutorial data binding como AngularJS

Tags: javascript

Boa noite,

Queria aprofundar o meu conhecimento de javascript ao entender o funcionamento interno de alguns frameworks.

Há algo que não consigo encontrar, como é que o AngularJS e o VueJS fazem o Data Binding na view.

Exemplo:

```
<body>
  <div>{{name}}</div>
</body>
<script>
//.. Blah
$scope.name = "Mariana";
</script>
```

Retorna

```
<div>Filipe</div>
```

Como calculo que a resposta seja um pouco longa, se alguém me pudesse apontar para um sitio que explique como se consegue este efeito, ficava bastante agradecido.

Obrigado desde já a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite. Sua pergunta é bastante interessante e criei um certo interesse nessa problemática. Após algumas pesquisas listei alguns artigos (espero que entenda um pouco de inglês :) ) que podem ajudar no entendimento dessa obra majestosa que é o AngularJs.

Para começo de conversa o que você vai ver em comum em todas as fontes são o métodos `$apply()` e `$digest()` que estão sendo explicados [**aqui**](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Demais perguntas, artigos, exemplos e explicações estão aqui: (foi o que encontrei)

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634666/how-does-angularjss-watch-function-work
- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts
- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/angularjs-how-does-databinding-work
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/angularjs-internals-in-depth/
- [Make Your Own AngularJS, Part 1: Scopes And Digest](http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html)

Sei que é uma bagunça enorme, mas para começo de conversa isso pode nos servir. Na própria documentação do angular há vários modelos gráficos representandos os loops referentes as mudanças dinâmicas no DOM.

**Boa sorte!**

Comment: Boas Samir, 

Agradeço-lhe mesmo a ajuda. 
Eu trabalho em engenharia de software e antes de começar algum trabalho mais sério que requira alguma tecnologia, gosto de aprender mesmo como ela funciona internamente, não imagina a ajuda que me deu neste momento.

Obrigado.

Comment: Fico bastante feliz em ter ajudado. Sua dúvida me fez buscar por algo que também me interesso, então obrigado também :) .